# Refresh TextView after executing AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, textview

I have problem with refreshing TextView after I get required data in AsyncTask. Everything would be fine if it was in single file, but I decided to split it. In first class I have TextViews and in another one I have few AsyncTasks which downloads data from net.
What I've already tried:

mainActivity:

```
summary.countCash(); // it runs AsyncTask in summary class
while (summary.wait) {
    // do nothing and wait until AsyncTask finishes
}

eCash.setText("Cash: " + summary.cash);
```

and in AsyncTask:

```
Boolean wait = false;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    wait = true;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    cash = result;
    wait = false;
}
```

Unfortunately it does not work. App freezes.
I also tried to set

```
wait = false;
```

at the end of doInBackground, but then in main I got summary.cash = 0, which is probably because it refreshes TextView before value is updated in onPostExecute.

Comment: why you don't update your `TextView` on `onPostExecute`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uhm, i don't advise to keep stuck at a continuous loop. It will keep the Activity busy. Just invoke a callback method from the AsyncTask class.

in `AsyncTask` class

```
private _mainActivity;

// constructor
public AsyncTask(MainActivity ma) {
    // passing reference
    _mainActivity = ma;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    _mainActivity.updateTextview(result);
}
```

and then in your `MainActivity`

```
public void updateTextview(Integer result) {
    // update textview using result
}
```

By this, your MainActivity wouldn't be stuck in a loop. Moreover, you can add a process dialog in the main activity and stop it in the `updateTextview` method.

### edit 1

You can call it by using the AsyncTask class as object. I don't know the class name, assume it's `AsyncTask` then use the next in your `MainActivity`

```
AsyncTask at = new AsyncTask(this);
at.execute();
```

the `this` points to the MainActivity itself, which will be a reference. The `AsyncTask` class then can use the reference to invoke a callback method to the `updateTextview()` method.

Comment: and how to call it? like this: new fillSummaryCash().execute(MainActivity.this);

Comment: "public class fillSummaryCash extends AsyncTask" is in my SummaryActivity class. so is this correct?  AsyncTask at = new SummaryActivity.fillSummaryCash(this);

Comment: it should be `fillSummaryCash fsc = new fillSummaryCash(this);` then. Just add a new class file, and wrap all your Async functionalities there. (OOP code standard)

Comment: it works. thanks. but what if I want to call the AsyncTask from two different activities?

Comment: you can do the same if the Async class is in a separate file and accessible from both activities. Android is capable to run two instances of AsyncTask from two activities. ( ps :if this answer helped you, please mark it as an answer that future users can see it directly)

Answer (score 1):

In your async task.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    eCash.setText("Cash: " + result);
}
```

Get rid of your while statement. You don't need it. 
Fyi, you are locking up the ui thread by waiting, defeating the purpose of the asynctask in the first place.

Hope this helps

Comment: as I mentioned, eCash is in main activity and AsyncTask is in summary, so I could not set it by eCash.setText, cause there is no eCash in summary class